# How can I use an aabbox to determine if a mesh is or is nearly a plane

Tags: c++

I would like to create a function in c++ that takes an aabbox and determines if the box contains a plane or a panel shaped mesh kind of like.

```
bool isPlaneLike(aabbox B){ if (..........){return true}}
```

There should be a way by calculating the thickness, width and depth of the box.  I just can't think of it.

Comment: Can you provide a link to documentation on aabbox? Are you you using [this](https://code.google.com/p/melting-math/source/browse/MeltingMath/headers/AABBox.h?spec=svn7f73af421d2c034db3e5252b5a4c2324a68373a6&r=7f73af421d2c034db3e5252b5a4c2324a68373a6)

Comment: If so aabbox is just a bounding box. Is there some other data about what could be in the box? Because an aabbox doesn't store that kind of information on its own...It only has it's own dimensions.

Comment: that is right it is an axis aligned bounding box.  I want to use it's dimensions to deduce weather or not to consider its contents planar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AABBox::GetMin()` gives you the bottom-left-front corner as a vector.

`AABBox::GetMax()` gives you the top-right-rear corner as vector.

To get the length of the side in the x direction, bind the different between the x values of the two vectors. Same goes for the two other directions.

```
Vec3 min = B.GetMin();
Vec3 max = B.GetMax();
double lengthX = Math.abs(max.x - min.x);
double lengthY = Math.abs(max.y - min.y);
double lengthZ = Math.abs(max.z - min.z);
```

Comment: So probably once I get the depth, width and height. I should assume the the smallest value is the thickness and test its value against a fixed percentage of the other two values if it is less than the percentage of either other value it should be planar.  Right?

Comment: Ah I understand now. You are trying to determine if the box itself is relatively flat in some direction. That's seems right. And you understand that an axis aligned box will only ever be flat along one of the axis, right? It won't orient in any other direction